# Display HTML string in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am trying to display an HTML string in UITextView. Here is the key line:

```
self.postPage.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myHTMLString)
```

The problem I saw is that the `<div>` tags `<img>` tags are still showing... is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how the string looks like? Which Tags?

Comment: It is regular html string, for example: <div><br></div><img src="http://....">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension String {
    var html2String:String {
        return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!.string
    }
}

"<div>Testing<br></div><img src=\"http://....\">".html2String  // "Testing\n￼"
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to add `try!` if you use Xcode 7.0.1.

```
extension String {
    var html2String:String {
        return try! NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will convert all the HTML tags into `NSAttributedString`.

```
extension String{    
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is like:

```
yourTextView.attributedText = yourHtmlString.convertHtml()
```